# Change group concat in mysql date to Indonesian date format using moments js

Tags: codeigniter, momentjs, group-concat

I'm going to convert date which came from database to locale date format (Indonesia) using moments. js in modal bootstrap by event click using codeigniter framework.

**This is my schema database design** 
[image]
**This is my view js by event click**

```
 $('.pengajuan-cuti').on("click",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "pengajuancuti/detail/" + id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
             //change single date to indonesia date 
            var cu_propose_date=data.tanggal_cuti;
            var cu_propose_date1 = new moment(cu_propose_date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
            change date came from GROUP_CONCAT mysql
            var tanggal_cuti=data.tanggal_cuti;
            var tanggal_cuti1 = new moment(tanggal_cuti).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
            $('[name="tanggal_ambil_cuti"]').val(data.tanggal_cuti);
            $('[name="cu_propose_date"]').val(cu_propose_date1);
            $('#cu_status_approve').val(tanggal_cuti1).attr("selected", "selected");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error get data from ajax');
            }
        });
```

Then this is my controller

```
public function detail($id)
{
    $data = $this->Pengajuan_model->getemployeedetail($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Then this is my model

```
function getemployeedetail($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(cu_date_date SEPARATOR ',') as tanggal_cuti FROM cu_cuti a, cu_employee b, cu_date_cuti c where a.cu_id_cuti_employee=b.cu_id_employee 
    and a.cu_cuti_date_id=c.cu_date_cuti_id and a.cu_id_cuti='$id'");
    return $query->row();
}
```

This is my results date wrong pengajuan cuti,
[image]

`pengajuan cuti` values are stored in database like this : 2016-02-14,2016-02-16,2016-02-17,2016-02-18

I know I'm wrong to using moment js but how can I make group concat works in single date as well?

This is my simple [demo](http://codepen.io/sidaurukfreddy/pen/oboOMz/)

Comment: Hi, and welcome.  As is, your question is quite unclear.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Thanks.

Comment: hey @MattJohnson it already solved by my self please see the answer, all i need just group_concat(cu_date_date) with format dd-mm-YYYY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after digging one hours and leave it one days, i found another ways to convet it all to indonesia date using convert mysql date, so i change the model bellow here

```
 function getemployeedetail($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT( cu_date_date, '%d-%m-%Y' ) SEPARATOR ',') as tanggal_cuti FROM cu_cuti a, cu_employee b, cu_date_cuti c where a.cu_id_cuti_employee=b.cu_id_employee 
        and a.cu_cuti_date_id=c.cu_date_cuti_id and a.cu_id_cuti='$id'");
        return $query->row();
    }
```

Hope this help poor programmers in the future !